# YouTube API issue too_many_recent_calls

Tags: php, zend-framework, youtube, youtube-api, socialengine

I am getting an error while using youtube api.

here is the error i am getting,

```
exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 403 ' in /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Gdata/App.php:700 Stack trace: #0 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Gdata.php(221): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL) 
#1 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Gdata/App.php(861): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array) 
#2 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Gdata/App.php(754): Zend_Gdata_App->get('http://gdata.yo...', NULL) 
#3 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Gdata/App.php(220): Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...', NULL) 
#4 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Gdata.php(187): Zend_Gdata_App->getEntry('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...') 
#5 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Gdata/YouTube.php(293): Zend_Gdata->getEntry('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...') 
#6 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/modules/Videofeed/controllers/ProfileController.php(37): Zend_Gdata_YouTube->getVideoEntry('14NiccpyGt8') 
#7 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): Videofeed_ProfileController->indexAction() 
#8 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction') 
#9 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(946): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http)) 
#10 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(75): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch() 
#11 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160): Core_Bootstrap->run() 
#12 /usr/share/nginx/www/application/index.php(194): Engine_Application->run() 
#13 /usr/share/nginx/www/index.php(24): include('/usr/share/ngin...') 
#14 {main}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, I'm unsure if this can be a reason for the broken API. YouTube, last week, made in a change in their API. Something because of that?

Answer (score 0):

You're running into quota limits. This blog post has more information: http://apiblog.youtube.com/2010/02/best-practices-for-avoiding-quota.html